# .tsv file python, concatenate two columns in one string, str and int problem

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a .tsv file. First few rows look like this:

```html
genome  locus_tag   gene    substrate
PalbDSM11370    02121   susC    pululan
PalbDSM11370    02122   susD    pululan
PalbDSM11370    01210   susC    arabinan
PalbDSM11370    01209   susD    arabinan
PalbDSM11370    02015   susC    bglukan
PalbDSM11370    02016   susD    bglukan
PpalDSM17968    00934   susC    pululan
......
```

I am trying to read a file in pandas like this:

```
PULs = pd.read_csv('PULs.tsv', sep = '\t')
PULs["genome_locus_tag] = PULs["genome"] +"_"+ PULs["locus_tag"].astype(str)
print(PULs["genome_locus_tag"])
```

and I get a result like this:

```html
PalbDSM11370_2121   
PalbDSM11370_2122
PalbDSM11370_1210
....
```

But I want to tell that the *locus_tag* column is also a str so I would get a result with **0** in front of other numbers. Maybe I am not approaching in the best way since I am new with python.

Thanks!

Comment: when you read in your `tsv` file you should tell `pandas` that `locus_tag` should be interpreted as a string column, not an integer

Comment: sure, i specified in the answer that I need to do that, unfortunatelly dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to ensure having 4 digits? use [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
PULs["genome_locus_tag"] = (PULs["genome"] + "_"
                           +PULs["locus_tag"].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
                           )
```

output:

```
0    PalbDSM11370_2121
1    PalbDSM11370_2122
2    PalbDSM11370_1210
3    PalbDSM11370_1209
4    PalbDSM11370_2015
5    PalbDSM11370_2016
6    PpalDSM17968_0934
Name: genome_locus_tag, dtype: object
```

If you want to automatically use the largest number as reference:

```
N = int(np.ceil(np.log10(df['locus_tag'].max())))

PULs["genome_locus_tag"] = (PULs["genome"] + "_"
                           +PULs["locus_tag"].astype(str).str.zfill(N)
                           )
```

Alternative:

If your tsv if already formatted with leading zeros, specify the dtype:

```
PULs = pd.read_csv('PULs.tsv', sep = '\t', dtype={'locus_tag': 'str'})
```